How to calculate the mechanical properties of a setructure using CP2K?
I'm a beginner using cp2K and I want to calculate the mechanical properties of a structure. I've read that is it possible to calculate them by the Hessian matrix, then compute the elastic constants and with this calculate properties such as Young modulus.
The other way is use the structure with different volume and then fit the energy and volume to Birch–Murnaghan equation of state. Could you help me how to configure the input files of any of these cases

+1. Welcome to our community.
